# Parameterize $x^{2n+1} + y^{2n+1} = 2 x^n y^n$

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, parametric

How to parameterize $x^{2n+1} + y^{2n+1} = 2 x^n y^n$ where parametrization is of form
$$ x(t) = \rho(t) \cos^{\alpha} t $$
$$ y(t) = \rho(t) \sin^{\alpha} t $$
When I put that in the equation above, I got
$$\rho(t) (\cos^{\alpha (2n+1)} t + \sin^{\alpha (2n+1)} t) = 2 \sin^{\alpha n} t \cos^{\alpha n} t$$ I have tried something like $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$ and similar things but I have got nothing. Can someone please help?

Comment: Did you try $\alpha(2n+1) = 2$?